# Youtube API V3 authentication. Uploading to shared account

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, google-authentication

I'm trying to update an existing Asp.Net application using C# to avoid the Youtube V2 API deprecation.  The 1st challenge is figuring out how to authenticate using the new API.

This is how the application currently authenticates:

```
    string developerKey = (My Developer Key here);
    string username = (My username here);
    string password = (My password here);

    ytService = new YouTubeService("SampleApplication", developerKey);
    ytService.setUserCredentials(username, password);
```

I've researched, and reviewed the V3 API examples, and they all use OAuth2 to Authenticate like this:

```
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }
```

However, that prompts the user to login to their own Google account, and for this application we want all uploaded videos to go into our account.  Therefore I would like to continue using the Public API access if possible, and I can't find any examples of this for the V3 APIs.

I've also investigated OAuth2 Service Account, but for the life of me can not figure out how to authenticate using one of those.

Can you help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue recently, except I was working with a shared `Google Calendar` instead of a `Youtube` account.  What I ended up doing was adding an `authorize` button that only I could see, which was hooked up to the initial authorize request when clicked.  It opened the popup from `Google`, I gave the permission from the shared account, and I stored the returned access token, refresh token, and expiration date in the database.

Then, whenever users need to view the shared calendar, I just have logic that says if the expiration date has passed, use the stored refresh token to request a new access token and reset the expiration date, then I use the access token to make my `Google Calendar` API call (getting the events list, in this case).

Comment: Do refresh tokens ever expire?

Comment: @TroyG Nope, the refresh tokens to not expire.  The only way they can be invalidated is if the user revokes access to your application.

Comment: Thanks so much.  How do I get the refresh token in C#?  What Class do i use to authenticate that returns it?

Comment: @TroyG I actually didn't use any of the Google libraries.  Using [the Google oAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), I was able to see the raw requests and responses in their examples.  I used that instead of the libraries, forming my own requests and parsing the responses myself.  If you decide to go that route, I'd be happy to help you out!

Comment: Sorry for perhaps a dumb question, but with the oAuth playground, I could just initialize there, and then use the refresh token they give me right?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  That refresh token is app specific, so it only grants access for requests from the oAuth playground, not any others.  You'll still have to generate the oAuth request from your application to get your own refresh token.

Comment: Ok well then could you help me out by perhaps sharing an example of your request and parsing?

Comment: You were so helpful in getting to where I am, but I'm still struggling a bit.  I've got my refresh token.  I've got code that refreshes it, and gets me a new active token.  However, I'm having trouble using it.  In order to upload a video I need a "UserCredential" object.  How do I create a "UserCredential" object using my Token?

Comment: did you use a YoutubeService without credentials and manually injected the token in the requests?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, V3 of the YouTube API does not support service accounts, and oAuth2 is the only authentication method.

One of the reasons behind this is to do away with having multiple individuals upload into a single account; the legal liability (for both YouTube and app developers) is too great. The only current alternative is the YouTube direct lite program (which has multiple clients ... see YouTube's [Github](https://github.com/youtube) page to find them), which gives you a simple management/admin pane for autogenerating a playlist based on users uploading videos into their own accounts (in other words, they upload the video through your app, to their account, but your account gets a record of it and manages what can/can't appear on the list).

Comment: Surely there is a way that I can programatically upload to a fixed account.  Right?

Comment: @jeffreypmoran has an answer below that could help you get a refresh token ... you'd have to code up a page to manually trigger (one time) an oAuth2 request and capture the token, then store it in your app for use whenever you need to get an oAuth2 access token.